# HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject Method not returning required resources

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext

On switching Language from UI I am expecting resource in respective language but I am always getting English resource as shown below.
I am trying to access local resources in my "inplant-printing-dashboard.ashx" as below,

```
public static string GetLocalResource(string resourceKey)
{
string Status = HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject
("~/resource/handlers/inplant/
inplant-printing-dashboard.ashx",
resourceKey,    
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture
(Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["lang"])))
 as string;
    return Status;
}





I have resource files 
-inplant-printing-dashboard.it.ashx.resx( 'it' for Italian)
-inplant-printing-dashboard.ashx.resx (default for English)
-[![enter image description here][1]][1]
-
```

I am supposed to get resource in Italian when I change language to Italian  but I don't understand why HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(...) returns resource in English always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the format of your resx filenames may be incorrect. The language code should come after the pagename, and before the resx extension, like so:

*inplant-printing-dashboard.ashx.**it**.resx*

*inplant-printing-dashboard.ashx.**fr**.resx*

See here for more details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer made my day.